# Limit $\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{j=2}^k e^{\bigl(\pi - k\sin\frac{(j-1)\pi}{k}\bigr)\ln k} = 2$?

Tags: limits, summation

By numerical experiment, I guess the following limit
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{j=2}^k e^{\bigl(\pi - k\sin\frac{(j-1)\pi}{k} \bigr)\ln k} = 2.$$

But how to prove it? I have no idea.

```
import math
sum = 0
k = 100000
for j in range(2, k+1):
    sum += math.pow(math.e, (math.pi -  k * math.sin((j-1) * math.pi / k)) * math.log(k))

print(sum)
```

Comment: Do you mean 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{j=2}^k e^{\bigl(\pi - k\sin\frac{(j-1)\pi}{k} \bigr)\ln k} = 2?$$
because this indeed seems to be the case.

Comment: @DankaMakabre Yeah, it should be two. I changed from `range(2, k)` to `range(2, k+1)`

Comment: Just by looking at it you might be able to do some somplifications with $e^{\ln{k}}$ to get something on the form of a Riemann sum. Maybe then you can convert it to an integral for which it will be easier to show what you are seeking. Might be wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

Your numerical experiment is weird. For $j=2$ and $j=k$ the summand is equal to $e^{(\pi-k\sin(\pi/k))\ln k}$, which converges to $1$. So if your sum converges it should be to something at least equal to 2.

Comment: And for other values of $j$, the term is at most something like $1/k^\pi$, so even adding $k$ of these we still get something going to $0$.